# Appending individual text file chars to string in C via strcat()

Tags: c, string, strcat

I am trying to read in a text file char by char and append each char to a string.

This code here outputs what I expect, showing each individual char:

```
        char currentStr[MAX_WORD_LEN] = ""; 
        char cStrConvert[1] = "";
        char c;
        while((c = fgetc(filePtr)) != EOF)
        {
            cStrConvert[0] = c;
            printf("\ncStrConvert:%s\n", cStrConvert);
            //strcat(currentStr, cStrConvert);
            printf("\ncurrentStr: %s\n", currentStr);
        }
```

This is the output of the above:

```
cStrConvert:w

currentStr: 

cStrConvert:o

currentStr: 

cStrConvert:w //and so on for all the chars in the text file
```

However, when I make an attempt to append these chars to a string via strcat(); the code below,

```
        char currentStr[MAX_WORD_LEN] = ""; 
        char cStrConvert[1] = "";
        char c;
        while((c = fgetc(filePtr)) != EOF)
        {
            cStrConvert[0] = c;
            printf("\ncStrConvert:%s\n", cStrConvert);
            strcat(currentStr, cStrConvert);//try to append to the string
            printf("\ncurrentStr: %s\n", currentStr);
        }
```

```
cStrConvert:w

currentStr: w

cStrConvert:ow

currentStr: wow

cStrConvert:wwow

currentStr: wowwwoww
```

I have distilled this behavior to the one line that changes between the two code blocks, however I have no clue as to why it is not just appending each char to the currentStr. Additionally, strcat() seems to be changing cStrConvert as well.

### Edit 2: Solution

I changed my definition of

```
char cStrConvert[1] = "";
```

to

```
char cStrConvert[2] = "";
```

to account for, and to be able to hold the null terminator character

Comment: Your definition `char cStrConvert[1] = "";` makes `sStrConvert` only able to hold one single string: The empty string. The assignment `cStrConvert[0] = c;` will turn it from a string into a non-string. After that assignment you can't use the array as a string anymore.

Comment: Why do you need to use `strcat()` for this? Use a variable to hold the current end of the string, assign the character to that index, and increment it.

Comment: Also note that [`fgetc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) returns an **`int`**. Which is very important when you want to compare the result to the `int` value `EOF`.

Comment: You need to make `cStrConvert` big enough to hold the null terminator in addition to the character.

Comment: As for the program ad the exercise, you don't need the `cStrConvert` at all. Just keep track of the current position into `currentStr` and assign directly to that element.

Comment: @Some Programmer Dude This was the intuitive approach for me. For context, outside of the scope of my question if I reach a whitespace char (indicating the end of the string), I have to preform an action on that string and then repeat the process for the next. 


I am trying to understand what you mean; would that way work, just keeping track of and overwriting the correct index of the string, for say a really long string followed by a short string? Wouldn't there still be the end of the long string hanging out? 


E.g: Howdy followed by Cat, overwriting by char -> Catdy

Comment: To give an example: `int c; for (size_t i = 0; i < MAX_WORD_LEN && (c = fgetc(filePtr)) != EOF; ++i) { currentStr[i] = c; }`. From that it's easy to add handling for special characters.